java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper In Oracle R12 Java Conccurent Program
We have designed one Java concurrent program to generate an XLSX file. For this, we used Apache-poi jar files (copied to $OA_HTML/WEB-INF/lib/), but we are getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper
It worked initially, but after the CUP patch and Java and JRE version changes, the program started giving this error.
We tried multiple versions of the Apache-poi jar but still had the same error.
But when we un-JAR and copy in JAVA_TOP it works

[Edit] your question and post the entire stack trace (for the NoClassDefFoundError).
